# Why cors module can not be found?

Tags: node.js, next.js, cors

I'm trying to enable `cors` for my next.js API.

Based on [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction#caveats) and [the example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/api-routes-cors/pages/api/cors.ts) I installed cors:

```
npm i cors
```

And I can verify that it's in my `package.json`:

```
"cors": "^2.8.5",
```

And it's in my `node_modules` directory.

However, when I use `import Cors from 'cors'` in my api code, I get this error:

> Module not found: Can't resolve 'cors'

Why do I get this error while the package is installed? I also tried `const cors = require('cors')` and got the same error.

Comment: can you put some code snippits and show how you use cors

Comment: try this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nextjs-cors

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: I don't know why you being downvoted, I think I had the same problem as you some time ago.
doing ```const cors = request('cors);``` won't work for modern EE5 or ES6, use ```import cors from "cors";```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can try delete node modules and package-lock.json:

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm -f package-lock.json
npm cache clean --force

npm install
```

After this be sure that `cors` is in your dependencies on package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "cors": "version",
  },
```

if not you can try to manually add the line with desired version and run `npm install`

If still not working you can try:

```
npm install cors --save
```

in your main project directory

Comment: I did all of that, but I still get the same error.